# Train Direct Route Query

Tags: oracle

Let's say I've a table `trainStations` with the following:

```
 startStation  | endStation
 --------------+--------------
 SF            | Palo Alto
 Palo Alto     | SF
 Mountain View | Redwood City
 SF            | Palo Alto
 Palo Alto     | Mountain View
 Mountain View | SF
```

Now, I'm trying to learn how to do a round trip query.
For example, to query `SF --> PA` I'd use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   trainStations 
WHERE  startStation = 'SF' 
AND    endStation = 'Palo Alto'`
```

But how do I query for round trip (with no additional stops)?

For example: `SF--> Palo Alto --> SF`

It should return the two lines:

```
 startStation  | endStation
 --------------+--------------
 SF            | Palo Alto
 Palo Alto     | SF
```

Only `SF -> Palo Alto` followed by `Palo Alto -> SF` rows are valid (direct route). The last three rows (in the table above) will not be selected because it's not a direct route (stop in Mountain View).

If this was code I'd do something like:

```
if (startStation[row num] == endStation[row num+1]) 
    && (endStation[row num] == startStation[row num +1):
then print "found direct route"
```

Comment: That implies there is (or should be) additional information available to make the call.  A SQL table is a "bag" of data; data only has a defined order when your query defines it. So, there is absolutely no difference between the first (SF, Palo Alto) row and the second. And, logically speaking, if the train lets you get on in SF and get off in Palo Alto, and it doesn't stop in between them, it's a direct route. Even if there's a route number missing, you could use routes 1 and 3 to get to PA; you'd have to use route 3 to go back to SF without a stop.

Comment: @Simply_me rows in SQL tables have no inherent order. If the rows in the specific table are describing sequential parts of a route, you need to add more column(s) to have that info (eg. `route_id, part_no`)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you another approach:

> ```
> create table TrainStations
> (
>     RouteId int, 
>     OrderId int, 
>     StartStation varchar(50), 
>     EndStation varchar(50)
> );
> ```

By adding Route and Order (Stops), you can get the whole journey of no matter what route.

> ```
>     SELECT RouteId,
>            OrderId,
>            StartStation, 
>            EndStation
>       FROM TrainStations
>      WHERE RouteId = 3
>   ORDER BY RouteId, OrderId;
> ```
>
> ```
> ROUTEID | ORDERID | STARTSTATION  | ENDSTATION   
> ------: | ------: | :------------ | :------------
>       3 |       1 | SF            | Palo alto    
>       3 |       2 | Palo alto     | Mountain View
>       3 |       3 | Mountain View | SF
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f998c0a627d5d7b387abf77666bab00f)*

Or if you want a single line:

> ```
>     SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT (t1.StartStation, ', '), 
>                   (SELECT LISTAGG(t2.EndStation, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.OrderId)
>                    FROM TrainStations t2
>                    WHERE t2.RouteId = t1.RouteId)) Route
>     FROM   TrainStations t1
>     WHERE  t1.RouteId = 3
>     AND    t1.OrderID = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ROUTE                            |
> | :------------------------------- |
> | SF, Palo alto, Mountain View, SF |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18bf453f3d8747b7634c385093ffb7eb)*

Comment: thank you for posting an answer. Can you translate your solution to the example above? I don't think your answer shows how to pick a non stop route.

Comment: Simply change RouteID = 1

Answer (score 2):

Modified version of McNets's answer, showing how to find a "round trip" route (two consecutive legs, first A to B, second B to A):

Query:

```
SELECT RouteId, OrderId, StartStation, EndStation
  FROM (
        SELECT RouteId,
               OrderId,
               StartStation, 
               EndStation,
               LEAD(StartStation) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY OrderId) as NextStartStation,
               LEAD(EndStation) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY OrderId) as NextEndStation
          FROM TrainStations
       ) two_stop
 WHERE StartStation = 'SF'
   AND EndStation = 'Palo Alto'
   AND NextEndStation = StartStation
   AND NextStartStation = EndStation
 ORDER BY RouteId, OrderId;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=79427213f1d956e9afb9c12630b6aa54)*

`LEAD` function lets you pull values from the next row in a group. In the `OVER` clause, the `PARTITION BY` defines the groups, and the `ORDER BY` how the rows are ordered within each group.  In the dbfiddle, try commenting out the first two and last six lines in the last query (the one shown above), and you'll see better how this works.

NOTE: This would *not* identify that Route 1 (starting at OrderId = 2) would presumably be a "Palo Alto" => "SF" => "Palo Alto" round trip. If that's true, you'd need a slightly more complicated query:

```
SELECT RouteId, OrderId, StartStation, EndStation
  FROM (
        SELECT RouteId,
               OrderId,
               StartStation, 
               EndStation,
               LEAD(StartStation) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY OrderId) as NextStartStation,
               LEAD(EndStation) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId ORDER BY OrderId) as NextEndStation
          FROM (
                SELECT RouteId,
                       OrderId,
                       StartStation,
                       EndStation
                  FROM TrainStations
                UNION ALL
                SELECT RouteId,
                       LoopId as OrderId,
                       StartStation,
                       EndStation
                  FROM (
                        SELECT RouteId,
                               OrderId,
                               MAX(OrderId + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY RouteId) as LoopId,
                               StartStation,
                               EndStation
                          FROM TrainStations
                       ) loopLeg
                 WHERE OrderId = 1
               ) loopedStations
       ) two_stop
 WHERE StartStation = 'Palo Alto'
   AND EndStation = 'SF'
   AND NextEndStation = StartStation
   AND NextStartStation = EndStation
 ORDER BY RouteId, OrderId;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab6b3bb0b29545f0aa11a46de6dfaf18)*

Here, we add the first leg of each route (OrderId = 1) back in as a new last leg. This will catch that a round trip from SF to Palo Alto and back would start at Route 1, OrderId 1, and a round trip from Palo Alto to SF would start at Route 1, OrderId 2. Ignore if that doesn't fit the logic you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I query for round trip (with no additional stops)?

That's easy.. because you're defining the problem as "with no additional stops".

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE startstation = 'Palo Alto' AND   endstation = 'SF'
    OR  endstation   = 'Palo Alto' AND startstation = 'SF'
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE 2 <= (SELECT count(*) FROM t);
```

If that returns then you have a bidirectional direct-route. This case can be simplified if you're `UNIQUE(startstation, endstation)`.

Normally however you do this with a shortest path algorithm. In this case, you would assign the cost to be "stops" normally, however your costs are more complex. Like for instance, if a single additional stop saves you the price to charter an empty plane, is it worth it? Almost certainly, yes.